# After shapefile to GeoJSON conversion coordinates look wrong?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, geojson, iceland

I have downloaded a shapefile of Iceland. Here is the source: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7a21f6f05b8d45848ed16298cbf96d59.

I then converted the shapefile to geojson, using this tool: [shapefile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile).

```
shp2json Postnumer_heild/Postnumer_heild.shp -o ispc.json
```

The problem is that the coordinates look wrong. Here is the first feature from the geojson:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"FITJUFLOKK":101,"STJORNSYSL":10,"POSTNR":113,"NAFNFITJU":"ReykjavÃ­k","LYSING":null,"VINNSLUFER":4,"DAGSINNSET":"2002-02-06T23:00:00.000Z","DAGSHEIMIL":"1899-11-29T23:00:00.000Z","NOTANDI":"BG","DAGSLEIDRE":"2005-05-31T22:00:00.000Z","DAGSUPPFAE":"1899-11-29T23:00:00.000Z","BREYTANDI":"BG","GAGNAEIGAN":"SamsÃ½n","HEIMILD":"LMÃ, ÃslandspÃ³stur","POSTNUMER":"113","BIRTING":1,"CreationDa":"2019-10-31T23:00:00.000Z","Creator":"Hannesgud1","EditDate":"2019-10-31T23:00:00.000Z","Editor":"Hannesgud1"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-2418307.5714999996,9379398.261699997],[-2418549.5058999993,9379779.308300003],[-2418962.081099998,9380031.9054],[-2419644.0931,9380225.563100003],[-2420662.901299998,9380629.718400002],[-2421471.2118999995,9380924.415],[-2421513.3114,9380351.861699998],[-2421883.7870999984,9379956.1263],[-2422540.5394,9380048.7452],[-2423256.2311000004,9379863.507399999],[-2423684.1750999987,9379173.563699998],[-2424460.6569,9379570.873800002],[-2424559.5036999993,9379693.683399998],[-2424628.396899998,9379978.242399998],[-2424631.3922999986,9380259.806100003],[-2424613.4200999998,9380595.286200002],[-2424649.3643999994,9380885.835900001],[-2424634.387600001,9380957.7245],[-2424568.4897999987,9381071.548100002],[-2424427.707899999,9381167.399499997],[-2424182.0885999985,9381293.204599999],[-2424098.218600001,9381439.9771],[-2424059.278900001,9381670.6197],[-2424011.3532,9381667.624300003],[-2423996.3764000013,9381694.582500003],[-2424017.343899999,9381739.512900002],[-2424065.2696,9381739.512900002],[-2424146.144299999,9381856.3319],[-2424199.0665000007,9382113.0546],[-2424196.8621000014,9382114.9322],[-2424129.5643000007,9382173.408699997],[-2423957.422699999,9382321.9384],[-2423844.9470999986,9382422.215899996],[-2423692.274599999,9382552.250299998],[-2423544.7256000005,9382680.827299997],[-2423397.1713000014,9382809.403300002],[-2423249.6116000004,9382937.979000002],[-2423102.046500001,9383066.553400002],[-2423096.5231,9383072.526500002],[-2422980.9800999984,9383197.465000004],[-2422918.2096999995,9383279.2949],[-2422813.842,9383420.768799998],[-2422743.7520000003,9383520.537500001],[-2422709.7657999992,9383569.012500003],[-2422701.3836000003,9383581.278300002],[-2422587.455499999,9383765.066200003],[-2422534.2606000006,9383880.134400003],[-2422481.0639999993,9383995.204099998],[-2422421.4250999987,9384169.529700004],[-2422375.955600001,9384285.845700003],[-2422333.2413000017,9384402.936700001],[-2422293.7333999984,9384521.6989],[-2422257.4158999994,9384641.239799999],[-2422232.193500001,9384725.057400003],[-2422208.8137000017,9384809.688900001],[-2422186.757100001,9384894.240599997],[-2422147.337000001,9385097.5352],[-2422096.291200001,9385200.1074],[-2422085.0771000013,9385270.653700002],[-2422147.3004,9385555.499899998],[-2422222.2041000016,9385692.067100003],[-2422277.6149999984,9385787.003700003],[-2422315.0731999986,9385875.645999998],[-2422287.618999999,9385935.264200002],[-2422221.1809,9385952.332000002],[-2421912.8484999985,9386057.861500002],[-2421817.4305999987,9386103.598300003],[-2421778.5064000003,9386184.3873],[-2421772.7212000005,9386196.394699998],[-2421724.7993,9386287.9806],[-2421674.0797999986,9386377.901299998],[-2421652.6631000005,9386412.9243],[-2421620.126699999,9386466.130900003],[-2421563.855700001,9386552.674099997],[-2421525.9842000008,9386607.0828],[-2421504.8077999987,9386637.505900003],[-2421472.1292999983,9386681.493100002],[-2421443.3764000013,9386720.1959],[-2421379.1926999986,9386801.218400002],[-2421286.7534999996,9386907.86],[-2421191.0425999984,9387011.710500002],[-2420905.3517999984,9387282.217100002],[-2420736.5088,9387469.756899998],[-2420563.7139,9387656.145599999],[-2420362.6363000013,9387347.699100003],[-2420346.2875999995,9387353.626500003],[-2420344.3497,9387354.329400003],[-2420190.419399999,9387410.143700004],[-2419801.1873999983,9387551.260200001],[-2419673.517499998,9387597.541699998],[-2419400.8812999986,9387696.365999997],[-2419367.107500002,9387708.607199997],[-2419024.5582000017,9387832.7535],[-2418942.5549999997,9387862.4701],[-2418847.1323000006,9387897.0484],[-2418574.0557000004,9387995.994900003],[-2418544.4211999997,9388006.7319],[-2418523.471000001,9388014.322700001],[-2418026.652800001,9388194.307599999],[-2417939.399,9388225.913099997],[-2417915.4833000004,9388234.575999998],[-2417924.0023999996,9387985.504299998],[-2417939.350499999,9387536.751999997],[-2417941.1204999983,9387485.012199998],[-2417941.297699999,9387479.8327],[-2417918.3814000003,9387476.548299998],[-2417830.594799999,9387463.9644],[-2417457.8698000014,9387410.523599997],[-2417408.7553000003,9387403.480099998],[-2416601.7331999987,9387287.695299998],[-2416468.8555999994,9387240.344300002],[-2416148.296,9387126.101099998],[-2416078.3445999995,9387101.169299997],[-2415146.302099999,9386768.898000002],[-2415055.936999999,9386737.1188],[-2414646.162799999,9386592.9956],[-2414372.063000001,9386489.116400003],[-2414076.157200001,9386389.381499998],[-2414057.3500999995,9386384.093000002],[-2413638.284600001,9386234.384900004],[-2413280.780000001,9386106.646899998],[-2413257.9516000003,9386099.3732],[-2412208.901999999,9385726.168700002],[-2413176.0513999984,9385007.504100002],[-2413291.6281999983,9385120.577200003],[-2413433.3106999993,9385022.810999997],[-2413568.3068999983,9384722.590000004],[-2413780.1699,9384738.156099997],[-2413817.1444000006,9383621.160400003],[-2413854.6235999987,9383606.911799997],[-2413880.0874999985,9383609.015299998],[-2413936.7776000015,9383633.146700002],[-2413996.5146000013,9383623.139200002],[-2414978.5441999994,9379034.6356],[-2415704.3341000006,9379151.5009],[-2416922.031100001,9379405.549099997],[-2418155.162999999,9379683.413199998],[-2418307.5714999996,9379398.261699997]]]}},
```

The first coordinate is for Reykjavik:

```
[-2418307.5714999996,9379398.261699997]
```

For Reykjavik, Iceland, I would expect something like `[64.xxxxx, 21.xxxxx]`.

If I load the shapefile into mapshaper, it looks like I would expect:

[image]

What has gone wrong here?

Comment: Please read up on what different CRS are, how they interact and especially, how conversion between them is possible in your software of choice.

Comment: Agree the coordinates in the GeoJSON are wrong, should be CRS:84 (long/lat) decimal degrees, and yours definitely aren't.

Comment: `For Reykjavik, Iceland, I would expect something like [64.xxxxx, 21.xxxxx].` for Reykjavik it should be `[-21.9426,64.1466]`

Comment: your issue is the library you are using [https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile] is states "This library does not support parsing coordinate reference system specifications" QGIS can reproject on the file